# Why is alpha socket empty in fire sim?

Tags: rendering, transparency, fire

[image]

None of these *Greater Than* nodes are working with fire sim, because **Alpha socket is empty** both in *RGBA node* and *RenderLayer pass*. The only way to see "alpha channel" is to uncheck **Use Alpha** in *Viewer* or *Composite* nodes (as on the screenshot).

Material setup for simulation is very basic: Flame/Density Attribute->Emission shader->Volume output

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do? [Fire](https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-bed9e3607121785f7d15d29b99e24d9d) (in general) doesn't occlude objects and therefore has very little alpha. Could you explain your actual goal?

Comment: Nothing particular really. During my last project noticed this thing and it seemed strange to me. So, a question about "actual goal" is more likely asked by me towards Blender. What is a point to have no visual of alpha but still use it (from technical side of view)?